# Only pipe when data arrives

Tags: python, linux, pipe

I trying to learn simple piping stuff on Linux:

**sender.py:**

```
# sender.py
import random
import sys
import time

while True:
    r = random.randrange(5)
    print(r)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**receiver.py:**

```
# receiver.py
import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print("hello " + line.strip() + " hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I do:

```
$ python sender.py | python receiver.py
```

I have the following output as expected:

```
hello 3 hello
hello 2 hello
hello 2 hello
hello 0 hello
...
^C
```

Until now, everything works as expected to me. The problematic part is the following. When I try to do:

```
$ echo "50" | python receiver.py
```

The output I expect to have is:

```
hello 50 hello
```

However, instead, I have the following line occurs infinitely many times:

```
hello  hello
```

My questions:

1. What is going on? What is the logic behind "echo "50" | python receiver.py" ?
2. Is there a way to change my **receiver.py** so that it only prints `hello 50 hello` once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the input indefinitely, when there is only one input provided. You need to make your script `break` when there is nothing received:

```
# receiver.py
import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print("hello " + line.strip() + " hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> ...if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached...

Change your code to this:

```
import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not len(line):
        break
    print("hello " + line.strip() + " hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```